# Is it possible to create a process with a non-existent Windows account?

Tags: c#, process, account

I would like to start process as user that non-existent in Windows. Is this possible? If not, can I create temporary account with admin rights, start process as this user and delete that account before application closing? Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Sounds like someone's up to no good...

Comment: I want to shutdown PC in local subnet. For good functioning Shutdown.exe needs to be running under same account as it running on the computer you want to shutdown. You can create account on PC from where you want to call shutdown.exe, but imagine, that you want to shutdown about 20 PC's (don't want to create 20 accounts in Windows). PS: I dont want to use 3rd party software.

Comment: Smells like internet cafe dirty work.

Comment: No, any dirty work, it's for my own home subnet :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, *if* the user that originally runs your code is an admin. To make it happen, you need two processes. The first process needs to create the user, kick off your 2nd process using the new account, wait for the 2nd process to finish, and then delete the user.

Comment: He does mention specifically that he wants to delete the user _before_ the app closes.